# SubtleCrypto.encrypt: Argument 2 is not an object. When trying to encrypt using web crypto API

Tags: javascript

So i was making an asymmetric encrypt and decrypt app, it gives the user the option to generateKey both public and private key and output it as a string. But then when the user inputs plain text and the public key that is in string (i only took the modulus of the string). An error came which probably means that the key must be an object when encrypting (my assumptions). Im trying to import the key from string to an object for the last two days but failed everytime. Is the error actually because of the key isnt an object or is it something else? heres the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const generateBtn = document.querySelector('.generateBtn');
  const bitLength = document.querySelector('.keyLength');
  const publicKeyTextarea = document.querySelector('.publicKeyTextarea');
  const privateKeyTextarea = document.querySelector('.privateKeyTextarea');
  const plainTextInput = document.querySelector('.plainTextInput').value;
  const cipherTextInput = document.querySelector('.cipherTextInput').value;
  const publicKeyInput = document.querySelector('.publicKeyInput').value;
  const privateKeyInput = document.querySelector('.privateKeyInput').value;
  const encryptBtn = document.querySelector('.encryptBtn');
  const decryptBtn = document.querySelector('.decryptBtn');
  let publicKey;

  async function generateKeyPair(bitLength) {
    return await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: bitLength,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: "SHA-256"
      },
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );
  }
  
  async function encrypt(publicKey, plaintext) {
    const encodedText = new TextEncoder().encode(plaintext);
    return await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
      {
       name: "RSA-OAEP"
      },
      publicKey,
      encodedText
    );
  }
  
  async function decrypt(privateKey, ciphertext) {
    const decryptedBuffer = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP"
      },
      privateKey,
      ciphertext
    );
    return new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedBuffer);
  }
  
  async function main() { 
    generateBtn.addEventListener('click', async function(){
      const keyPair = await generateKeyPair(bitLength.value);
      publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
      const privateKey = keyPair.privateKey;
      const publicKeyString = await exportKeyAsString(publicKey);
      const privateKeyString = await exportKeyAsString(privateKey);
      publicKeyTextarea.value = publicKeyString;
      privateKeyTextarea.value = privateKeyString;
    })
    encryptBtn.addEventListener('click', async function(){
      const plainText = document.querySelector('.plainTextInput').value;
      const publicKeytext = document.querySelector('.publicKeyInput').value;
      if (plainText == '' || publicKeytext == ''){
        window.alert('Please enter both fields to encrypt');
        console.log(plainText);
        console.log(publicKeytext);
      }else{
        try{
          const publicKey = await importPublicKey(publicKeytext); // Wait for the promise to resolve
          await encrypt(publicKey, plainText);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Encryption error:", error);
        }
      }
    });
    // const plaintext = "Hello, world!";
    
    // const encrypted = await encrypt(publicKey, plaintext);
    // console.log("Encrypted:", new Uint8Array(encrypted));
  
    // const decrypted = await decrypt(privateKey, encrypted);
    // console.log("Decrypted:", decrypted);
  }
  
  async function exportKeyAsString(key) {
    try {
        // Export key as JWK (JSON Web Key) format
        const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
            "jwk",
            key
        );
        // If the key is a private key, return the private modulus
        if (exportedKey.d) {
            return exportedKey.d;
        }
        // If the key is a public key, return the public modulus
        return exportedKey.n;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error exporting key:", error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error to propagate it to the caller
    }
  }

// async function importPublicKey(publicKeyString) {
//   try {
//     // Parse the JSON string into a JavaScript object
//     const publicKeyObject = JSON.parse(publicKeyString);

//     // Import the public key using the parsed object
//     return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
//       "jwk",
//       publicKeyObject,
//       { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256" },
//       true,
//       ["encrypt"]
//     );
//   } catch (error) {
//     console.error("Error importing public key:", error);
//     throw error;
//   }
// }


  
//   async function importPrivateKey(privateKeyString) {
//     try {
//       const privateKey = JSON.parse(privateKeyString);
//       return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
//         "jwk",
//         privateKey,
//         { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
//         true,
//         ["decrypt"]
//       );
//     } catch (error) {
//       console.error("Error importing private key:", error);
//       throw error;
//     }
//   }

  main();
})
```

I tried turning the key to an object thinking that it will fix the problem because the encryption process can only take object but i just dont know how to do it. Nothing worked, and i've made my assumptions that theres another way instead of turning the key string into an object

Comment: Turn this into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run e.g. on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (console outputs are sufficient).